# Using dos, how can I rename existing folders switching the date parts around?

Tags: dos

I have a set of folders already named mm-dd-yyyy (for example 01-01-2014) but they will be more useful named yyyy-mm-dd (for example 2014-01-01).  Using dos, how can I rename the folders switching the date parts around?

Comment: *Really* MS-DOS, or the `cmd` interpreter under Windows?

Comment: @paxdiablo Sorry, I am old, from the days of MS-DOS!  Forgot to use the proper term.

Comment: @hunny Thanks for reminding me about using dir to create a file.  Here is what I did: dir  /b /ad *.* > directorylist.txt; copy the contents of directorylist.txt into Column B and Column C in Excel file; on Column B do Format Cells>Custom and for the Type: use mm-dd_yyyy; on Column C do Format Cells>Custom and for the Type: use yyyy-mm-dd.  Put rename into every cell of Column A. Copy all to Notepad and save as a .bat file, drop it into folder (containing 1,000 files to be renamed) and run the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about `cmd.exe` rather than the ancient MS-DOS `command.com`, you can do this reasonably easily<sup>(1)</sup>.

The idea is to iterate over all directories in the current directory, using `for /d`. Then, for each one that matches a specific pattern (`99-99-9999`), you can use string manipulation to construct a `rename` command.

The checking for a correct format can be done with the regular expression capability of `findstr`.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Process every file. For each file with a valid format,
rem   construct a rename command.

for /d %%a in (*) do (
    set full=%%a
    call :isvalidfmt !full!
    if !res!==true (
        set d2=!full:~0,2!
        set m2=!full:~3,2!
        set y4=!full:~6!
        echo ren !full! !y4!-!m2!-!d2!
    )
)
endlocal
goto :eof

rem Use findstr regex option to see if file name is correct format.

:isvalidfmt
    set res=true
    echo %1|findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" >nul:
    if errorlevel 1 set res=false
    goto :eof
```

Note that the script above (let's call it `rengen.cmd`) simply outputs the `rename` commands, it does not actually rename the files. That's good practice so you can see what it's going to do *before* you destroy your directories :-)

To actually rename the files (once you've confirmed it's safe), simply capture the output to another file then run *that*:

```
rengen >nextren.cmd
nextren
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If you *are* talking about `command.com`, I can't help you out there. The command interpreter has come a long way since those bad old days and the one that came with MS-DOS is seriously under-powered.

Answer (score -1):

use dir and export to a file. Take it to Excel and create two columns, one with current name and one with new name and then bring it back to notepad and add RENAME command to each row as a prefix.
RENAME cuurentfilename newfilename is the command syntax.